# How to place two drop down parameters near by, by giving one a common label in ssrs 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

I am using ssrs 2008 to generate report, i have two parameter which has drop down, Period from(MM) parameter has numbers 1 to 12 in drop down list and Period from(YYYY) parameter has 2011,2012,2013 in dropdown list

In preview tab in parameter section it shows

Period from(MM): dropdown1                   Period from(YYYY): dropdown2

but i want to use a single label and give two parameter next to next like below

Period From(MM/YYYYY): dropdown1 dropdown2

Answer (score 0):

SSRS 2008 do not support single label for two parameters, even you cannot set their spacing between them. SSRS only gives you an option of parameter ordering i.e one after another but not for their alignment.

For your problem i can suggest following solutions:

1) You can use "Period From(MM/YYYYY):" label for first parameter and populate it with month values. Now for second parameter use space " " as a label for second parameter and populate it with year values. (NOTE: You cannot change the spacing between the parameters)

2) You can use single label for single parameter with values populating from a query in "MM/YYYY" format. You can use today's date as base for creating multiple month-year combinations.

Thanks,
Neeraj

Comment: You actually can change spacing between parameters by modifying the SSRS CSS file(s) - I've needed to do this to lock control widths at a reasonable size so that very long values in the database wouldn't resize a dropdown list and skew the page formatting.